# Allow Users to Save Image From NSImageView (Swift)

Tags: swift, image, macos, save, nsimageview

I am looking to allow users of an app to save the image displayed in a NSImageView to a chosen directory. (not one specified by me, in the code). I know I should use a modal window to allow them to choose, but nothing comes handy right now. Any ideas, tips? Thank you!

Comment: OS X provides you with standard [Open and Save Panels](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/UsingtheOpenandSavePanels/UsingtheOpenandSavePanels.html)

Comment: yeah, I am trying to use those, it provides me the correct path, but it does not save the actual image. Here, I am editing the question with my code :D

Comment: never mind, got it!